# How to load an image and rotate it according to it's orientation exif data and save it with UIImageOrientationUp exif data

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, uiimageorientation

How to load an image and rotate it according to it's `orientation` `exif` data and save it with `UIImageOrientationUp` exif data (or without any orientation exif data) so that software that don't handle exif orientation data will show correctly the image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading an image is as simple as this line:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfImageHere"];
```

Or if you got image data:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] init];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

And following method will help you to fix the orientation using exif data within `UIImage`

```
- (UIImage *)imageByFixingOrientation {

    UIImage *image = self;

    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, image.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, image.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, image.size.width, image.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.height,image.size.width), image.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height), image.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 equivalent of my previous objective-c method as an extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    func byFixingOrientation(andResizingImageToNewSize newSize: CGSize? = nil) -> UIImage {

        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return self }

        let orientation = self.imageOrientation
        guard orientation != .up else { return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: .up) }

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        let size = newSize ?? self.size

        if (orientation == .down || orientation == .downMirrored) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi)
        }
        else if (orientation == .left || orientation == .leftMirrored) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
        }
        else if (orientation == .right || orientation == .rightMirrored) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: -(CGFloat.pi / 2))
        }

        if (orientation == .upMirrored || orientation == .downMirrored) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0);
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        }
        else if (orientation == .leftMirrored || orientation == .rightMirrored) {
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.height, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        }

        // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform calculated above.
        guard let ctx = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height),
                                  bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0,
                                  space: cgImage.colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: cgImage.bitmapInfo.rawValue)
        else {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: orientation)
        }

        ctx.concatenate(transform)

        // Create a new UIImage from the drawing context
        switch (orientation) {
        case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
            ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.height, height: size.width))
        default:
            ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: ctx.makeImage() ?? cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: .up)
    }
}
```

**Usage-1**

```
let newImage = image.byFixingOrientation()
```

**Usage-2 (Fix orientation and resize image to new size)**

```
let newImage = image.byFixingOrientation(andResizingImageToNewSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
```

Comment: thanks @AamirR ! if i do newImage = image.byFixingOrientation() and then i save the newImage to a file (jpeg), what will be the orientation Exif data of the image?

Comment: `.up` will be the new orientation, so that it will not be automatically processed by exif orientation aware program

Comment: I just try your solution, it's didn't work :( when i try to load the resulting image with a non exif orientation aware program then the image is displayed in the wrong orientation :(

Comment: I try to compile, if i not make any mistake CGContext(data: nil, width: ...) is equivalent to CGBitmapContextCreate but i don't see the equivalent of ctx.concatenate(transform) :(

Comment: CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);